# Search and replace string with carriage return before a table

Tags: microsoft-word

When doing a search and replace for a string of text including a carriage return, I can find the string, but not replace it.

Example: I need to look for the string "Text" immediately followed by a carriage return (`^p`) and replace it with "NewText", so I search for `text^p` and want to replace it with `NewText^p`

I cannot look for just "Text" as if it does not appear at the end of a paragraph (see second paragraph in my example), I do not want to replace it.

Original doc:
[image]

After a search and replace:
[image]

Word can find both instances in my example. Why won't it replace both? Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Seems like a bug in Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in Word: if there's a table after the paragraph `^p` sign, the repalce command won't work correctly.

As workaround, you'll have to do your replace in two steps:

1. Replace `Text` with `NewText`
2. Replace `NewText`  with `Text` , using a space at the end of the search string, to change back the occurencies which you do not want to modify.